# PostgreSQL query works locally (9.x), but gives syntax error on Heroku (8.x)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I developed my site and it works like a charm on my local machine. The query is supplied by a fellow Stackoverflow member [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985767/too-many-order-by-max-subqueries-for-my-intellect).

[schema.rb portion that is relevant](https://gist.github.com/2916931)

Same data locally as on Heroku.

```
select  *
from    (
        select  *
        ,       row_number() over (partition by odds_type order by odds_index desc) as rn2
        from    (
                select  *
                ,       row_number() over (partition by event_id, bookmaker_id, odds_type 
                                           order by created_at desc) as rn1
                from    Odds
                where   event_id = #{e.id}
                ) sub1
        where   rn1 = 1
        ) sub2
where   rn2 = 1
```

**The error in the console**

```
Odds Load (88.4ms)  select * from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by odds_type order by odds_index desc) as rn2 from (select *, row_number() over (partition by event_id, bookmaker_id, odds_type order by created_at desc) as rn1 from Odds where event_id = 21 ) sub1 where rn1 = 1 ) sub2where rn2 = 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "over"
LINE 1: select * from ( select *, row_number() over (partition by od...
                                           ^
```

Comment: I really wish Heroku would upgrade to a less prehistoric Pg release; this sort of question is coming up a lot. The popularity of Heroku is making Pg seem slower, less capable, and (by virtue of big version differences) buggier than it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**row_number()** and [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-window.html) in general are available in PostgreSQL 8.4 or higher. The error indicates that you're trying this query on an older version (8.3?), so it can't work.

Update: after studying the original question and answer with PG 9.x, I believe you could obtain the same result with the PostgreSQL-specific [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) clause, non-standard but available in older versions of PG and quite handy in your case. Here's my proposal:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (ot) bi,ot,oi FROM
  (select distinct on (bi,ot) bi,ot,oi from odds
    where ei=1 order by bi,ot,created_at desc) subq
 ORDER BY ot,oi DESC;
```

Comment: Any suggestions on rewriting this 8.3 compatible?

Comment: Given that the purpose of row_number() seems to be to keep only the first row in the nested sub-queries, it might be doable with ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1.

Comment: Answer updated with a variant based on DISTINCT ON that works with 8.3

Comment: That works almost. I need the `bookmaker_id` in the select as well, so I can generate links to the bookmaker website. Not sure where/how to insert that into this particular query.

Comment: Answer updated again with one more level of `distinct on` to access the `bi` column.